# Objects in blender won't render

Tags: rendering

I am attempting to render an image but only the white plane that I am using in the background will render.

Comment: We will need a lot more information to provide a conclusive answer, but try pressing `Alt`+`H` int eh viewport, and making sure the objects are not on different layers/Renderlayers

Comment: Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: What solved it @Sharice? I will post it as an answer so we can get this off the un-answered list

Comment: I must say, trying not to answer this question whilst I wait is like staring at roast beef after lent.

Comment: @ARadish Same here, I have been waiting for him to confirm my comment for an hour now :P